# Ansible Dynamic Variables in Playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm provisioning a bunch of systems (VMs) on a physical host. I'm up to the step where the VM's are running. Now I need to ssh into the VM's via their DHCP addresses. I can pull the IP addresses from the server but I need a way to set these to host_vars. Here are my groups:

```
ok: [kvm01] => {
    "msg": {
        "all": [
            "kvm01",
            "dcos-master-1",
            "dcos-agent-1",
            "dcos-agent-2",
            "dcos_bootstrap"
        ],
        "dcos": [
            "dcos-master-1",
            "dcos-agent-1",
            "dcos-agent-2",
            "dcos_bootstrap"
        ],
        "dcos-agents": [
            "dcos-agent-1",
            "dcos-agent-2"
        ],
        "dcos-bootstraps": [
            "dcos_bootstrap"
        ],
        "dcos-masters": [
            "dcos-master-1"
        ],
        "kvm": [
            "kvm01"
        ],
        "ungrouped": []
    }
}
```

Here's my command:

```
- name: Get the IP of the VM (DHCP)
  command: "/getip.sh {{ item }}"
  register: "result"
  with_items: "{{ groups['dcos'] }}"

- name: List the output of the variables
  debug: msg="{{item.stdout}}"
  with_items: "{{result.results}}"
```

When I run the playbook I get results but they are the FULL JSON result of the command rather than the stdout. There's probably a way to pull out the stdout and assign it to a fact but it's a complex hash. Here's the last result:

```
TASK [vm_install : Get the IP of the VM (DHCP)] ***************************************************************************
changed: [kvm01] => (item=dcos-master-1)
changed: [kvm01] => (item=dcos-agent-1)
changed: [kvm01] => (item=dcos-agent-2)
changed: [kvm01] => (item=dcos_bootstrap)

TASK [vm_install : List the output of the variables] **********************************************************************
......
    ok: [kvm01] => (item={'_ansible_parsed': True, 'stderr_lines': [u'] => {
    "item": {
        "changed": false,
        "cmd": [
            "/getip.sh",
            "dcos_bootstrap"
        ],
        "delta": "0:00:00.056193",
        "end": "2017-09-18 15:45:45.409693",
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "_raw_params": "/getip.sh dcos_bootstrap",
                "_uses_shell": false,
                "chdir": null,
                "creates": null,
                "executable": null,
                "removes": null,
                "warn": true
            }
        },
        "item": "dcos_bootstrap",
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2017-09-18 15:45:45.353500",
        "stderr": " ",
        "stdout": "192.168.1.130",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "192.168.1.130"
        ]
    },
    "msg": "192.168.1.130"
}
```

How can I put the output of the command into an array so that I can use it later in my playbook?

Comment: Re-read the ansible docs concerning [loops and register](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#using-register-with-a-loop) and see if that helps. Your second task needs to iterate over the results of the first task (and `register: "{{ item }}.ip` is probably erroneous; you will want to register to a simple named variable, like `register: hostips`).

Comment: I've updated my question after doing some debugging and actually getting a result. My problem now is that the result that I'm getting back is not stdout...it's the FULL result data dumped from ansible. Obviously I only want what was returned from the command.

Comment: No, you're getting exactly what you want. Look at the bottom of your output, where you see `"msg": "192.168.1.130"`.  That's the "output" of the `debug` task (i.e., the result of the `msg:` key).  Everything else you see there is debugging information and can be ignored. I think you're all set.

Comment: I updated my question again after I cleaned up my script. I've found a workaround for the issue for now (by saving the output to a file and picking it from there) but I'd really like to know how to accomplish this using an "Ansible-preferred" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, like I said in my comment, you've already managed to extract the information you want into an array.  You can iterate over those items using `with_items` as in the follow task that will create an `ip_address` for each host:

```
- set_fact:
    ip_address:  "{{ item.stdout }}"
  with_items: "{{ results.results }}"
  delegate_to: "{{ item.item }}"
  delegate_facts: true
```

Or you can create a single array containing all of the addresses using Jinja filters:

```
- set_fact:
    all_ip_addresses: "{{ results.results|map(attribute='stdout')|list }}"
```

Or you could create a dictionary with the same information:

```
- set_fact:
    all_ip_addresses: >
      {{ all_ip_addresses
         |default({})
         |combine({ item.item: item.stdout })}}
  with_items: "{{ results.results }}"
```

Comment: This is a great start. Is it possible to map the results to a hash with the hostname and the associated IP?

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for!